# How can i create packet with GRE header using scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I found an example in this pdf http://www.secdev.org/conf/scapy_Aachen.pdf .

```
send(IP(dst="1.1.1.1",proto="GRE")/'\x00\x00\x00\xfe\x83\x1b\x01\x06\x12\x01\xff\x07\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff \xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01\x07\x00\x00')
```

but i get `KEY ERROR "GRE"`
Maybe someone can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer myself. A correct packet is built and send with

```
send( IP(dst="")/GRE(proto=254)/b’\x83\x1b\x01\x06\x12\x01\xff\x07\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01\x07 \x00\x00’)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

sendp(Ether(dst="00:00:00:00:00:03")/IP(dst="10.0.0.2")/GRE(key_present=1,key=900)/fuzz(Ether(dst="00:00:00:00:00:03")/IP(dst="10.0.0.2")/TCP()/Raw(load="GRE tunnels FTW")))

works